# Use maven-antrun-plugin to unzip multiple files with regex definition for the file

Tags: java, maven, ant, unzip, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to use the `maven-antrun-plugin` in order to unzip a file. How can this file be defined by using a regular expression? E.g. unzip all files that match: `sample[0-9].zip`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/{REGEX_GOES_HERE}.zip" dest="${project.build.directory}/dest/" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are those files generated during the maven build ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Ant [Unzip task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) by specifying to consider it a [fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) where the file names match a given regular expression.

```xml
<unzip dest="${project.build.directory}/dest/">
  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
    <filename regex="^sample[0-9].zip$"/>
  </fileset>
</unzip>
```

In the above snippet, all ZIP files under `${project.build.directory}` whose name are exacly `sample[0-9].zip` will be unzipped into `${project.build.directory}/dest/`.